# reason: Apex CPU time limit exceeded (refine the codes)

Tags: apex, trigger, map, cpulimit

Im struggling to fix this CPU time problem, I have tried to refine my code as good as possible by implementing maps and as can be seen below;

```
public class dailyUpdates2{

    /// used for converting the aggregated results back to IDR (they are in EUR by default) //
    public Decimal conversionID = [SELECT ConversionRate FROM CurrencyType WHERE IsoCode = 'IDR'][0].ConversionRate;   
    public Id ppRecordType = TDeal__c.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Sales Target').getRecordTypeId();
    public List<Mortgage__c> mortgage = [Select Id,  FirstDownPayment2__c, NextDownPayment1__c, InstallmentCounter__c, NumberInstallments__c FROM Mortgage__c WHERE IsDue__c = TRUE AND StartDate__c != null];

   public void scheduledUpdates(){

        updateAgentPerformance();
        activeContractStage();
    }

    public void updateAgentPerformance(){

        System.debug(conversionID);

        /// Map of all TAgents with their SF ID ///
        List<TAgent__c> agents = [SELECT Id, NumTotalDeals__c, DealsLast6Months__c, EngagementLevel__c, DealsLast3Months__c, DealsLastMonth__c, MemberLevel__c, TotalDealValueCY__c FROM TAgent__c WHERE EngagementLevel__c != '0. Not onboarded yet'];
        Map<Id, TAgent__c> agentIds = new Map<Id, TAgent__c>();
        agentIds.putAll(agents);

        /// for each Agent get the number of all deals in the last 6, 3 ,1 month ///
        Map<Id, AggregateResult> agentDeals6 = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>([SELECT COUNT(Id) num, TAgent__c Id FROM TDeal__c WHERE TAgent__c IN: agentIds.keySet() AND DateOfSigning__c >= LAST_N_MONTHS:6 AND DealType__c <> 'Cancelled' AND RecordTypeId <>: ppRecordType AND SalesStage__c = '5. Deal Closed' GROUP BY TAgent__c]);
        Map<Id, AggregateResult> agentDeals3 = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>([SELECT COUNT(Id) num, TAgent__c Id FROM TDeal__c WHERE TAgent__c IN: agentIds.keySet() AND DateOfSigning__c >= LAST_N_MONTHS:3 AND DealType__c <> 'Cancelled' AND RecordTypeId <>: ppRecordType AND SalesStage__c = '5. Deal Closed' GROUP BY TAgent__c]);
        Map<Id, AggregateResult> agentDeals1 = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>([SELECT COUNT(Id) num, TAgent__c Id FROM TDeal__c WHERE TAgent__c IN: agentIds.keySet() AND DateOfSigning__c >= LAST_N_MONTHS:1 AND DealType__c <> 'Cancelled' AND RecordTypeId <>: ppRecordType AND SalesStage__c = '5. Deal Closed' GROUP BY TAgent__c]);

        /// for each agent get the number of Managed Agents and Team Members in their related list /// 
        Map<Id, AggregateResult> managedAgents = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>([SELECT COUNT(Id) num, Manager__c Id FROM TAgent__c WHERE Manager__c IN: agentIds.keySet() GROUP BY Manager__c]); 
        Map<Id, AggregateResult> teamMembers = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>([SELECT COUNT(Id) num, TeamLead__c Id FROM TAgent__c WHERE TeamLead__c IN: agentIds.keySet() GROUP BY TeamLead__c]);
        Map<Id, AggregateResult> referredAgents = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>([SELECT COUNT(Id) num, ReferredBy__c Id FROM TAgent__c WHERE ReferredBy__c IN: agentIds.keySet() GROUP BY ReferredBy__c]);

        /// for each agent get the number of events they attended in the last months --> based on task subject in their activity history ///
        Map<Id, AggregateResult> eventsLastMonth = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>([SELECT COUNT(Id) num, WhatId Id FROM Task WHERE (TaskSubject__c =: '1. Onboarding' OR TaskSubject__c =: '2. Small group gathering' OR TaskSubject__c = '3. Training' OR TaskSubject__c = '4. Product Knowledge') AND CompletedDate__c >= LAST_N_MONTHS:1 AND WhatId IN: agentIds.keySet() GROUP BY WhatId]);
        Map<Id, AggregateResult> eventsBeforeLastMonth = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>([SELECT COUNT(Id) num, WhatId Id FROM Task WHERE (TaskSubject__c =: '1. Onboarding' OR TaskSubject__c =: '2. Small group gathering' OR TaskSubject__c = '3. Training' OR TaskSubject__c = '4. Product Knowledge') AND CompletedDate__c < LAST_N_MONTHS:1 AND WhatId IN: agentIds.keySet() GROUP BY WhatId]);

        /// get the aggregated deal value for each agent within the current calendar year ///
        Map<Id, AggregateResult> dealValueCY = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>([SELECT SUM(DealValue__c) value, TAgent__c Id FROM TDeal__c WHERE TAgent__c IN: agentIds.keySet() AND DateOfSigning__c = THIS_YEAR AND DealType__c <> 'Cancelled' AND RecordTypeId <>: ppRecordType AND SalesStage__c = '5. Deal Closed' GROUP BY TAgent__c]);

        system.debug('managedAgents ' + managedAgents);
        system.debug('agent deals 6' + agentDeals6);
        system.debug('events last month ' + eventsLastMonth);
        system.debug('deal values ' + dealValueCY);

        /*loop through all agents of the map/list and update their fields according to the values from the aggregated results above */      
        for(TAgent__c agent : agents){

            if(agentDeals6.keySet().contains(agent.Id)){ /// if agent is in this map, i.e. he had deals within last 6 months
                agent.DealsLast6Months__c = (Decimal)agentDeals6.get(agent.Id).get('num'); /// update the field on the record
            }else{
                agent.DealsLast6Months__c = 0;
                if(agent.NumTotalDeals__c > 0){
                    agent.EngagementLevel__c = '1. No deal in last 6 months'; /// update the engagement level field which depends on the DealsLast6Months__c field /// 
                }
            }

            if(agentDeals3.keySet().contains(agent.Id)){
                agent.DealsLast3Months__c = (Decimal)agentDeals3.get(agent.Id).get('num');
            }else{
                agent.DealsLast3Months__c = 0;
                if(agent.DealsLast6Months__c > 0){
                    agent.EngagementLevel__c = '2. No deal in last 3 months';
                }
            }

            if(agentDeals1.keySet().contains(agent.Id)){
                agent.DealsLastMonth__c = (Decimal)agentDeals1.get(agent.Id).get('num');
                if(agent.DealsLastMonth__c == 1){
                    agent.EngagementLevel__c = '4. 1 deal in last month';
                }else if(agent.DealsLastMonth__c >= 3 && agent.DealsLastMonth__c <= 10){
                    agent.EngagementLevel__c = '5. 3+ deals in last month';
                }else if (agent.DealsLastMonth__c > 10){
                    agent.EngagementLevel__c = '6. 10 + deals in last month ';
                }
            }else{
                agent.DealsLastMonth__c = 0;
                if(agent.DealsLast6Months__c > 0 && agent.DealsLast3Months__c > 0 ){
                    agent.EngagementLevel__c = '3. No deal in last month';
                }
            }

            if(managedAgents.keySet().contains(agent.Id) && (Decimal)managedAgents.get(agent.Id).get('num') > 0){
                agent.IsManager__c = true;
                agent.ManagedAgents__c = (Decimal)managedAgents.get(agent.Id).get('num');
            } else{
                agent.IsManager__c = false;
                agent.ManagedAgents__c = null;
            }

            if(teamMembers.keySet().contains(agent.Id) && (Decimal)teamMembers.get(agent.Id).get('num') > 0){
                agent.IsTeamlead__c = true;
                agent.TeamMembers__c = (Decimal)teamMembers.get(agent.Id).get('num');
            } else{
                agent.IsTeamlead__c = false;
                agent.TeamMembers__c = null;
            }

            if(referredAgents.keySet().contains(agent.Id) && (Decimal)referredAgents.get(agent.Id).get('num') > 0){
                agent.ReferredAgents__c = (Decimal)referredAgents.get(agent.Id).get('num');
            } else{
                agent.ReferredAgents__c = null;
            }

            if(eventsLastMonth.keySet().contains(agent.Id)){
                if((Integer)eventsLastMonth.get(agent.Id).get('num') >= 3){
                    agent.AttendanceLevel__c = '4. Attended 3+ events within last month';
                }else if((Integer)eventsLastMonth.get(agent.Id).get('num') == 2){
                    agent.AttendanceLevel__c = '3. Attended 2 events within last month';
                }else{
                    agent.AttendanceLevel__c = '2. Attended 1 events within last month';
                }
            }

            if((!eventsLastMonth.keySet().contains(agent.Id)) && eventsBeforeLastMonth.keySet().contains(agent.Id)){
                agent.AttendanceLevel__c = '1. Attended >1 month ago';
            }
            if(dealValueCY.keySet().contains(agent.Id)){
                agent.TotalDealValueCY__c = (Decimal)dealValueCY.get(agent.Id).get('value')*conversionID; /// transform the sum (SF returned in SF) back to IDR 
                if(agent.MemberLevel__c != 'ElitePRO'){ /// request by Mart 11-09-2018: once an agent reached ElitePro level the level is not supposed to be updated --> excluded from update here
                    if(agent.TotalDealValueCY__c < 1000000000.00){
                        agent.MemberLevel__c = 'MemberPRO';
                    }
                    else if(agent.TotalDealValueCY__c >= 1000000000.00 && agent.TotalDealValueCY__c < 10000000000.00){
                        agent.MemberLevel__c = 'SilverPRO';
                    }
                    else if(agent.TotalDealValueCY__c >= 10000000000.00 && agent.TotalDealValueCY__c < 20000000000.00){
                        agent.MemberLevel__c = 'GoldPRO';
                    }
                    else if(agent.TotalDealValueCY__c >= 20000000000.00){
                        agent.MemberLevel__c = 'PlatinumPRO';
                    }
                }
            }else{
                agent.TotalDealValueCY__c = 0;
            }

        }

        update agents;

    }
}
```

I thought to split the conditionals into some separate methods that will be called in 5 mins interval using CRON job but dont know if this is a good or not good idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work fine if you push it into a [Database.Batchable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm) implementation, moving the TAgent__c query to be the SOQL query locator returned from start and moving the rest of the behaviour into the execute.

The point is: you decompose the problem space into pieces that are quite independent (I didn't spot any query that needs to see all the agents in one go).

I would also suggest you update your queries to always perform the Agent ID "IN" lookup field expression before any other part of the WHERE clause - this can massively improve SOQL query performance since lookup fields are indexed and most others are not.

Use of a batch means you don't have to mess about trying to write your own code to chain a sequence of smaller processes and also massively increases the number of rows you can process over-all (from a maximum of 50000 to 50 million - see the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_apexgov.htm)) as long as you use a query locator not iterable. You can also choose how many agent instances to process at a time using the scope size parameter on Database.executeBatch.

Comment: Hi Phil, so the execute method is basically where I run all my existing methods? and this class contains also method from different object as I was expanding the class to have more methods and is it possible to do multipe sObjects in batch apex?

Comment: The batch, when using a QueryLocator, runs over the results of a single SOQL query. You return the query from the start method. The execute method is then called repeatedly to process the query results a chunk at a time. The execute method can perform additional queries (like you do) to get additional data needed to process the objects it receives. It is a good idea to write apex classes responsible for the processing and have the batch pass the data into those classes, receive the responses and update or upsert necessary data.

Comment: See the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm) for further detail.